# How to select files within a directory and capture them in a state including relative path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file

I am looking for a way to select files through the file dialogue. The file selector needs to:

- be restricted to only directory selection
- capture all selected files in a single callback so that they can be set to a state
- include the relative path for all files in the file list

I've tried the file selector components from a few libraries such as `antd`, `react-dropzone`, `@rpldy/uploady`, `react-file-reader`, and `react-file-picker` already, but none seem to be able to fulfill all three requirements.

Comment: Please read what kinds of questions are [on-topic](/help/on-topic). Recommendation requests are specifically off-topic (from that page): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Uploady](https://react-uploady.org).

When using the webkitdirectory flag for the file input element, you do get the webkitRelativePath property in all browsers (at least chrome & firefox) per the spec.

Now, to get the list of files, you'd use the [useBatchAddListener](https://react-uploady.org/docs/api/hooks/useBatchAddListener/) hook.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Uploady, { useBatchAddListener } from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";

const MyUploadButton = ({ addFilesToState }) => {
  useBatchAddListener((batch) => {
    addFilesToState(batch.items.map(({ file }) => file));
  });

  return <UploadButton>Upload Files</UploadButton>;
};

const Uploader = () => {
  const [_, setFiles] = useState([]);

  return (
    <MyUploadButton
      addFilesToState={(files) => setFiles((prev) => [...prev, ...files])}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Uploady destination={{ url: "[upload-url]" }} webkitdirectory="true" debug>
      <div className="App">        
        <Uploader />
      </div>
    </Uploady>
  );
}
```

See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-webkitdirectory-with-batchadd-fulpr4?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a React library for that, but you can take a look at the [File System Access API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/). It only works in Chrome, though, but maybe that `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` works in other browsers and would be enough for your needs.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need a callback after the files are selected so that I can save the file list to a state. As far as I can tell this isn't possible with the native input.

Comment: There is no problem doing that with the `showDirectoryPicker` method. And I would assume the `<input ...>` supports the "change" event.